# scroll property in a child element of a parent div whose position is fixed

Tags: css

I here want to know a simple fact:

```
<div style="position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;overflow:scroll">
 <div style="position:relative">Large content</div>
</div>
```

Its fine.Again (overflow is placed within the child's style):

```
<div style="position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;">
 <div style="position:relative;overflow:scroll">Large content</div>
</div>
```

It doesn't scroll.

I simply want to know the simple reason. Anyone mind to tell me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that your parent gets the window height, and is limited to that. However, the child is not limited height-wise, and all the content is visible inside it.

For instance, if you have a text that is 2000px in height, on a 1920x1080 screen, the parent will have a height of ~1000px (visible area), but the child (with the content) will have 2000px in height and scrolling is not required. You can simply add a `height` or `max-height` style for the child, which will allow you to use scrolling.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bFsnk/) is your code, with 15 paragraphs of lorem ipsum text. You can inspect it to see the above.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bFsnk/1/) on the other hand adds a `max-height: 95%` to the child element, and scrolling is possible.

Answer (score 1):

first you should set a frame with height so
use `hight:;`

---

as an example : http://jsfiddle.net/XGcGw/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/9tKe3/

CSS

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```